# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError - stream csv to update database

Tags: csv, express, sequelize.js

I have a few hundreds of `csv` files located in s3 bucket. I am building a server would fetch those `csv` files and update my database with `Sequelize`.

I am running this task as a scheduler, and I am seeing these error on occasions. It does not happen all the time, so I am suspecting it is related to `Promises`.

Here is the code:

`FilesNames` consist a list of filenames. I then use `csvtojson` to read these `csv` from stream, and insert those data with `Sequlize`

```
fileNames.forEach(file => {
      const csvFilePath = `${new_url}${file}`;
      csv({
        noheader: true,
      })
        .fromStream(request.get(csvFilePath))
        .on('csv', (csvRow, rowIndex) => {
          Hydrograph.create({
            data: csvRow,
            gaugeId: Number(file.slice(10, -4)),
            percentille: PERCENTILLE[rowIndex],
            type: 'GAUGE',
          });
        });
    });
```

These are the error I am getting. Again these errors only show up sometimes.

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
>       at Query.formatError (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:363:16)
>       at query.catch.err (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:86:18)
>       at tryCatcher (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/leoqiu/apps/eflow-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)

Comment: What's your question? Are you looking to find out which item is causing the exception?

Comment: I am trying to find out why I am getting this error? Why is the error happening?

Comment: According to the error, you are trying to insert invalid data into a number field. To get more info or catch the offending row, add `.catch(console.log)` after your `.create` method

Comment: Like I said above, the problem only happens on occasions. It does not happen all the time. It is the same data being streamed, if there is something wrong with number field, then it should be happening all the time.